# Calculating steps from a min/max scenario, and steps should be nice numbers c#

Tags: c#, .net, math

Im working on a heatmap where i have to display zones on a map filled by a color calculated by a range of values.

I got the zone color part figgured out, but i also have to display 5 steps, each step providing a color and a value, explaining what the color means.

So, lets say i have a minimum value of 2654 and a maximum value of 6947.
This provides me with a range of 5 numbers, which are:

```
2654
3727,25
4800,5
5873,75
6947
```

Now what i want is to display these values as nice intervals, like this:

0 - 3000

3000 - 4000

4000 - 5000

5000 - 6000

> 6000

These values are ofcourse dynamic.
So it could be either huge numbers or small numbers.
Is there any way to do this?

**Update**

@roberto-carlos i tried your example below:

```
  var min = 900;
  var max = 12541;
  var steps = 5;

  var range = Enumerable.Range(0, steps).Select(i => min + (max - min) * ((double)i / (steps - 1)));

  foreach (var d in range)
  {
    var power = Math.Floor(Math.Log10(d));
    var inf = d - d % Math.Pow(10, power);
    var sup = d + (Math.Pow(10, power) - d % Math.Pow(10, power));

    if (d == min)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("0-" + sup);
    }
    else if (d == max)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(">" + sup);
    }
    else
    {
      Console.WriteLine(inf + "-" + sup);
    }
  }
```

However, this provides me with a result like this:

```
  0-1000
  3000-4000
  6000-7000
  9000-10000
  >20000
```

Is there any way to make the intervals "stick together" numberwise?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'nice'? Do you mean that you first decide that you would like to have 5 intervals and the boundaries should be determined in such a way that they seem 'rounded'?

Comment: you are not making any sense. quote "minimum value of 2654 and a maximum value of 6947" this does not provide anything to do with the number 5. 5 was chosen before the number were even known. So why not just use 5 as the divided number for the segments. x/5. or do the logic you applied above. first is min taken to first tenth max and then intervals of the next as per divided by 5.

Comment: There will always be 5 intervals/steps, but the amount of values and range of these values are dynamic. So what ive done so far is i calculated what each of the steps would be, from the provided min/max value. What i am looking for is to split these into categories that are basicly rounded to the nearest 100 or 1000 or 10000, whatever the number is.

Comment: @mp1990 Can you give me an example of the intervals "stick together" numberwise?

Comment: @roberto-carlos this is basicly what im trying to achieve: http://imgur.com/a/BUFnZ

Except for that the numbers can be of a wider range than that. The image is an example of a value ranging from 0 to x, calculating the groups within.

Comment: @mp1990 Can you give me an input and your wanted output?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
var list = new List<double> { 2654, 3727.25, 4800.5, 5873.75, 6947 };

foreach (var d in list)
{
    var power = Math.Floor(Math.Log10(d));
    var min = d - d % Math.Pow(10, power); 
    var max = d + (Math.Pow(10, power) - d % Math.Pow(10, power));

    Console.WriteLine(min + "-" + max);
}
/*
Result:
2000 - 3000
3000 - 4000
4000 - 5000
5000 - 6000
6000 - 7000
/*
```

Version 2:

```
var list = new List<double> { 2654, 3727.25, 4800.5, 5873.75, 6947 };
var min = list.Min();
var max = list.Max();

foreach (var d in list)
{
    var power = Math.Floor(Math.Log10(d));
    var inf = d - d % Math.Pow(10, power); 
    var sup = d + (Math.Pow(10, power) - d % Math.Pow(10, power));

    if (d == min)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("0-" + sup);
    }
    else if (d == max)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(">" + sup);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine(inf + "-" + sup);
    }
}
/*
Result:
0-3000
3000-4000
4000-5000
5000-6000
>7000
/*
```

Comment: Thats actually pretty close, except that if i fiddle with the numbers and get this range:

951
3718,5
6486
9253,5
12021

The result is this:

900-1000
3000-4000
6000-7000
9000-10000
10000-20000

This creates a gap in the beginning: 900-1000 to 3000-4000.
But maybe i can get around this by converting the values to 0 - 3000 and > 10000 in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Using linq putting into predetermined groups

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication42
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] intervals = {3000, 4000, 5000,6000};

            List<List<int?>> data = new List<List<int?>>() {
                new List<int?>() {2654},
                new List<int?>() {3727,25},
                new List<int?>() {3730,25},
                new List<int?>() {4800,5},
                new List<int?>() {5873,75},
                new List<int?>() {6947}
            };

            var results = data.Select(x => new { index = intervals.Select((y, i) => new { index = i, max = y }).Where(z => x[0] < z.max).FirstOrDefault(), data = x }).ToList();

            var groups = results.GroupBy(x => x.index != null ? x.index.index : intervals.Length).Select(x => new { key = x.Key, data = x.Select(y => y.data).ToList() }).ToList();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thats nice but how do i calculate the groups then? Which is basicly my issue here.

Comment: Do you want the groups linear, exponential, log, or fixed quantity?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I initially misunderstood your problem.

The following implementation should do:

```
static IEnumerable<Interval> GetIntervals(IEnumerable<double> values, int intervalsCount)
{
    if (values == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(values));

    if (intervalsCount <= 1)
        yield break;

    var orderedValues = values.OrderBy(v => v);
    var frontiers = orderedValues.Select(
        v =>
        {
            var scale = Math.Pow(10, (int)Math.Log10(v));
            return Math.Floor(v / scale) * scale;
        }).ToArray();

    for (var i = 0; i < frontiers.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        yield return new Interval(frontiers[i], frontiers[i + 1]);
    }

    yield return new Interval(frontiers[frontiers.Length - 1], double.PositiveInfinity);
}
```

And `Interval` is a simple helper struct:

```
struct Interval
{
    public Interval(double lower, double upper)
    {
        if (upper <= lower)
            throw new ArgumentException("The upper bound must be greater than the specified lower bound", nameof(upper));

        LowerBound = lower;
        UpperBound = upper;
    }

    public double LowerBound { get; }
    public double UpperBound { get; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        if (UpperBound == double.PositiveInfinity)
            return $" > {LowerBound}";

        return $"{LowerBound} - {UpperBound}";
    }
}
```

This outputs for `2654.0, 3727.25, 4800.5, 5873.75, 6947`:

```
2000 - 3000
3000 - 4000
4000 - 5000
5000 - 6000
> 6000
```

And for example, in case of a logarithmic scaled input `2.0, 56, 321, 5674, 12764` the output is:

```
2 - 50
50 - 300
300 - 5000
5000 - 10000
> 10000
```

Note that this implementation will not create uniform intervals, it will create intervals, such that each one includes one concrete input value. I'm not really sure if this is what you want, your requirements aren't all that clear.